# .append is only appending one item from a list to another

Tags: python

My "test" function should output a list of lists from "items" object whose first string element of each list within items is contained in header1 object list. Please See desired out put below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\Work\Projects\chromedriver')

my_url = "https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005FITA"

def make_soup(url):
  driver.get(url)
  m_soup = soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
  return m_soup 

main_page = make_soup(my_url)


headers1 = ['Group','Person in charge', 'Type of Service', 'Registered Care Categories*', 'Specialist Care Categories','Languages Spoken by Staff (other than English)','Single Rooms','Single Rooms', 'Shared Rooms','Facilities & Service']

tags = main_page.select(".profile-group-description.col-xs-12.col-sm-8>p")
items = [tag.text.replace('\n','').split('\n')[0].split(':') for tag in tags]

indexs = list(range(len(items)))

def test():
   selected = []
   for i in indexs: 
      if any(x in headers1 for x in items[i]):
         selected.append(items[i])
      return(selected)
```

Current Output:

```
[['Group', 'Excelcare Holdings']]
```

Desired Output:

```
['Group', 'Excelcare Holdings']
['Person in charge', ' Denise Marks (Registered Manager)']
['Type of Service', '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCare Home only (Residential Care)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t– Privately Owned\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t, Registered for a maximum of 44 Service Users \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
['Registered Care Categories*', '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDementia • Learning Disability • Mental Health Condition • Old Age \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
['Specialist Care Categories', "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAlzheimer's • Down Syndrome • Schizophrenia • Stroke \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"]
['Languages Spoken by Staff (other than English)', ' Bengali; Bangla, Polish']
['Single Rooms', ' 38']
['Shared Rooms', ' 3']
```

Comment: The `return` statement in `test()` is not indented correctly, making it break the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: For example, have you verified that `items` contains what you expect it to contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test()` function should be like:

```
def test():
   selected = []
   for i in indexs: 
      if any(x in headers1 for x in items[i]):
         selected.append(items[i])
   return(selected)
```

Notice the return statement is outside the for loop and not inside it.